# Windows 10 stuck at the welcome screen for an hour for a specific user

Tags: windows-10

For 2 days I have been trying to login to my main user account it takes over an hour to login to that specific user other user is opening in the usual time only and even safe mode didnt do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your question that other user accounts are fine. So this user profile is damaged, and needs to be replaced.

The easiest approach is to copy the data from the problem user profile to a neutral location (c:\temp).

Now from an administrative user (make a temporary Admin user if needed), make a new main user account, log into the new account and recover the data from c:\temp.

If you wish to use the same main user account name, then make very certain of your back in c:\temp, log into the temporary Admin account, delete the main user profile, restart and create the main user account.  Again, recover the data from c:\temp.

Comment: You mean like just copy the whole user folder and paste It in a new account won't this not install all the apps?

Comment: I would do both:  copy the entire folder to be sure you have it and also copy your data, email and all to the same place as that makes it easier to recover. Your apps do not get reinstalled but you will have to set them up again. That is usually not too troublesome.